# Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 C++/CLI Missing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, c++-cli, visual-studio-2019

I can't understand why I can't find C++/CLI project type in to **Visual Studio 2017**. I just updated my Visual Studio, and now I can't create any more Windows Forms applications.

[image: Visual Studio 2017 Project Options]

[image: Packages installed]

Comment: This apply also to vs2022

Answer (score 18):

Valid for visual studio 2017,2019,[2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp?view=msvc-170)

The answer is [solved in this visual studio community forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/30695/ccli-gone.html).

I copied the solution here for convenience:

Please make sure you have selected the component "C++/CLI support" in your installation;

1. Please launch the "Visual Studio Installer"
2. Modify your installed VS;
3. You can find the component "C++/CLI support" under thw workload "Desktop development with C++"

[image: Package to install using Visual Studio 2017]

Answer (score 2):

First, Microsoft implementation of C++/CLI is called CLR so you want to look for CLR project type when creating new project.

Second, it's an optional component in Visual Studio 2017.

From the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/walkthrough-compiling-a-cpp-program-that-targets-the-clr-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019):

> In Visual Studio 2017 and later, C++/CLI support is an optional component. To install it, open the Visual Studio Installer from the Windows Start menu. Make sure that the Desktop development with C++ tile is checked, and in the Optional components section, also check C++/CLI Support.

The 2nd screen shot you have shared, go to `individual components` tab and select C++/CLI option (that's how it appears there).

I haven't not tested this for VS2017 but I did test it for VS2019 and that's what needs to be done. I am pretty sure it's the same for both visual studios.

Here is the screenshot for VS2019.

[image]