# How to convert a C++/CLI project from vcprj to vcxprj using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++-cli, visual-studio-2017

I'm migrating a C++/CLI project from VS2008 to VS2017 but I always get an error when "reloading" the project to convert.

The project don't load and I don't see any clear error message about the reason.

Comment: Added a better explanation of the issue and the solution. I don't understand why someone has downvoted this question. Please, leave a comment of the reasons. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the correct components of Visual Studio 2017 are installed.

May be it's not installed by default in your case. It happened to me when I installed Visual Studio 2017 using this [chocolatey package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/VisualStudio2017Community)

You can solve this issue with the steps in this question: [Visual Studio 2017 Professional C++/CLI Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298794/visual-studio-2017-professional-c-cli-missing/44373457#44373457)